# Remove myself from a shared agent on Dialogflow

Tags: dialogflow-es

Is it possible to remove myself from an agent that has been shared with me? I have quite a few agents in my console that are owned by other users - I can't find any options in the settings to remove them and don't want to bother the owners if I can help it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes possible,

simply go to google cloud console (https://console.cloud.google.com/)

select the project with name/projectid same as dialogflow agent:
[image]

then goto IAM section and remove yourself from IAM.

[image]
[image]

all google products including dialogflow and firebase are based on google cloud.